# jQuery table rebuild

Tags: jquery, html-table

We have a table:

```
<table>
<tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>3</td>
    <td>4</td>
    <td>5</td>
    <td>6</td>
    <td>7</td>
    <td>8</td>
    <td>9</td>
    <td>10</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

We update this table by throwing into each `<tr>` only **3** `<td>`.

It must look like:

```
<table>
<tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>3</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>4</td>
    <td>5</td>
    <td>6</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>7</td>
    <td>8</td>
    <td>9</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>10</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

How can we do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it using [`.unwrap()`](http://api.jquery.com/unwrap/), [`.slice()`](http://api.jquery.com/slice/), and [`.wrapAll()`](http://api.jquery.com/wrapAll/), like this:

```
var elems = $("table tr td").unwrap();
for(var i = 0; i < elems.length; i+=3) {
  elems.slice(i, i+3).wrapAll("<tr></tr>");
}​
```

[You can view a quick demo here](http://jsfiddle.net/trGzV/), this takes the `<td>` elements, removes the surrounding `<tr></tr>`, groups them in sets of 3 and re-wraps those groups in `<tr></tr>`.